# Weird Booting Problem with Debian Squeeze

Tags: debian, windows, dual-boot

I have a Windows XP/Debian Squeeze (XFCE desktop) dual-boot set up on a Dell Latitude laptop. The Windows XP portion boots fine. However, sometimes the Debian portion does not boot. If it doesn't boot, and I do a hard reboot, it will boot the second time. However, sometimes Debian will boot the first time.

How can I diagnose this problem?

All help appreciated!

[EDIT] I should mention that the improper boot manifests itself as a failure to reach the login screen. I see the standard Debian wallpaper with the stars and so on, but it doesn't display the login box.

Comment: In the Grub menu (where you choose between Linux and Windows), edit the Linux command to remove the words `quiet` and `splash` from the line that begins with `linux /vmlinuz`. Where does the boot hang? What are the last few messages on the screen (since you won't be able to copy-paste, try to take a legible picture)?

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try. It might be a little while before I can do that, though.

Comment: I'm using the Windows boot loader, not Grub, to choose into which OS I wish to boot. Can I edit the boot.ini file in Windows somehow to achieve what you're suggesting?

Comment: Regardless of what you use to choose your OS, there's a bootloader that loads Linux. What is it? Grub? Lilo? Syslinux? Something else?

Comment: I'm using Grub for Linux.

Comment: Incidentally, I have not had this problem occur again in some time.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is the graphics driver that is causing the problem. Can you boot to console in failsafe (recovery mode)? Check and regenerate your `xorg.conf` file, make sure all the settings are right.

Comment: It's a Latitude E5400. The graphics card, according to the dxdiag routine in WinXP, is a Mobile Intel(R) 4 Series Express Chipset Family card. As for booting to cli, would I do #update-rc.d -f gdm remove? Remember I have XFCE, although I did not do a Gnome-free Debian install. Sorry, newbie here. How do I regenerate xorg.conf? Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could do that with update-rc.d, if it doesn't work for you just remove it (aptitude remove gdm). Regenerate xorg.conf with dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg. Also, have you tried booting to recovery mode (failsafe) like I suggested in the answer? Try that before you do anything else.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a buggy driver, now the problem is to find out which.
The first thing to investigate is to look at the logs: `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Note that that latter file is restared each time you boot; if you've rebooted into X since the failure, the previous log will be in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`.

The OS may gave crashed before it could write the logs, but there is probably a message on the console. To make this message appear, you need to deactivate the boot-time splash screen. With Grub 2, edit `/etc/default/grub` and change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to just `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`. Hopefully, the next time the bug prevents your system from booting normally, the last few lines on the screen will tell you what's wrong.